# Need help to merge overlapping time intervals

Tags: postgresql

I need some help with merging overlapping time intervals if the interval not more than 4 minutes (for example only where id = 1).

I have the next table:

```
--------------------------------------
id | action    | date
--------------------------------------
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:51:02
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:51:04
2  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:52:14
2  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:52:17
3  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:52:21
3  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:52:24
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:57:21
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:57:22
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 15:07:56
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 15:08:56
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 15:09:11
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 15:09:11
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 15:09:11
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 15:09:13
```

Expected result:

```
--------------------------------------
id | action    | date
--------------------------------------
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:51:02
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:51:04
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 13:57:21
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 13:57:22
1  | started   | 2020-08-18 15:07:56
1  | suspended | 2020-08-18 15:09:13
```

How it can be done? I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: You will have to write some code to get this done. The normal way to keep a question within the allowed bounds on SO is to start the work yourself, then show us what part of that you are having problems with.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag the specific database only.

Comment: For each source row clarify like "this row must be stored/removed because ..."

Comment: Well, it's feasible but you would be better off coding that.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Finezxc, please try query. Also this query has comments

Answer (score 1):

You want to eliminate suspended/start pairs that are for the same id and within 4 minutes.  Use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_date,
             lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where (action = 'start' and
       prev_date > date - interval '4 minute'
      ) or
      (action = 'suspended' and
       next_date < date + interval '4 minute'
      );
```

Date/time functions are notoriously database dependent.  This is just adding or subtracting 4 minutes, which any database can do but the syntax might vary.

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to filter out certain rows, what is common with the rows you are removing?
It seems you want the *first* 'started' and *last* 'suspended' rows.  Can you just ignore 'started' rows if there is another 'started' row in the previous 4 minutes, and ignore 'suspended' rows if there is another 'suspended row in the next 4 minutes?

```sql
from my_table a
where action = 'started' and not exists (
    select 1 from my_table b
    where b.id = a.id and b.action = 'started'
      and datediff(minute, b.date, a.date) <= 4 -- row exists in the previous 4 min
)
```

Ditto for 'suspended' but the other way.  That doesn't work if the difference between the last 'started' and 'suspended' is > 4 minutes though, but that can be overcome with another condition to check for no start within the last 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get overlapping intervals duration not more than 4 minutes, can use this query:

```
--cte where creating groups with time intervals
with base_cte as
(
select Tab.id,Tab.NumGr,Tab.date,
Tab.action from
(
select * from
(
--selecting only values where time difference <= 4 min 
 select *,sum(TimeDiff)over(partition by id,NumGr order by date rows unbounded preceding)SumTimeInterval from
  (
--creating a group 
   select sum(Num)over(partition by id order by date rows unbounded preceding )NumGr, * from
    (
     select date,lead(date)over(partition by id order by date)lead_date,id,action, 
     lead(action)over(partition by id order by date)lead_action,
     --split intervals between overlaps (240seconds)
      iif(TimeDiff>240,1,0)Num,TimeDiff from
      (
       --find time difference in seconds between current and next date (partition by id)
        select datediff(second,date,LEAD(date)over(partition by id order by date))TimeDiff,* from Table
      )A
    )B
  )C 
  --selecting only pairs within time intervals
  where TimeDiff<=240
--checking duration interval:<=4 min
 )D where SumTimeInterval<=240
)E

CROSS JOIN LATERAL
(values (id,NumGr,date,action),
        (id,NumGr,lead_date,lead_action)
)Tab(id,NumGr,date,action)

)

--selectig data with start/end overlapping time interval
select id,date,action from base_cte base 
where date 
in (select max(date) from base_cte where NumGr=base.NumGr)
or date in
(select min(date) from base_cte where NumGr=base.NumGr)
```